# Scythe: Can I leave resources in the lake?

Tags: scythe

Playing with the Polania faction in Scythe, I built the mech than unlocks "Submerge". This allows my leader and mechs to travel in and out of lakes. At one point my leader was carrying resources with him during a lake-walk and I didn't want to bring them ashore. The reason was that the other faction would have a great opportunity to steal my resources while on dry land.
**Question: Was I allowed to go ashore leaving the resources(the oil :)) floating in the lake?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to https://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/20771925#20771925

> SUBMERGE: Your character and mechs may move to and from lakes and move from any lake to another (similar to tunnel movement, but with lakes). If a mech moves workers onto a lake or if a character or mech moves resources onto a lake, you may not leave those workers or resources on the lake after moving off of it, nor may a worker move off of the lake without the assistance of the mech.